# Is faces-config.xml necessary in a JSF, Spring, Spring-Security project?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jsf, spring-security

I have created a project of Spring ,Spring Security and Hibernate.In integrated project as we know Spring Security works by using interceptors and basically based on request oriented framework but jsf is component based framework.So how this request will be handled in this environment.Is it necessary to provide `faces-config.xml` along with `hibernate.cfg.xml` and `applicationContext.xml` (for Spring Security Configuration)? Or is just setting filter in `web.xml' sufficient?

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

If its a JSF project then faces-config.xml is mandatory. This is where you'll have your bean definitions and navigation rules.

Comment: You can refer to this link where "Injecting Managed beans in JSF 2.0" program is there under "Managed Bean " heading.link:- http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/jsf-2-0-tutorials/.  Here I found out that no faces-config.xml is not necessary and program is working fine.Please tell me under which circumtances it is necessary to add faces-config.xml to web project because without it ,project works fine.